# Is there any way to download the last modified file from a Sharepoint Site?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am able to successfully download a file from Sharepoint site but the problem is that the filename will not be the same. What I want to do in the below script is to modify the list by last modified time and download the latest one.

Here is the code I have till now

```
$source = "https://one.mysite.com/FileName.csv"
$destination = ".\NewFileName.csv"
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.credentials= new-object
System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyIDToAccessSource","Password", 
"MyDomain")
$webclient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

I believe Get-ChildItem works only for drives.

Thanks for your help
Sash

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting to download the file with the same name as on SP?

Comment: It doesnt matter if the filename is the same or different. My objective is to download the latest file from a particular sharepoint folder.The problem is that the filename is not the same. Say, if the last file is xxx_20.csv, the latest modified file can be xxx_50.csv. I basically am looking at sorting by last modified date and getting the filename and then downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint API you could construct the query that returns the latest modified list item (file) from a library.

The following example demonstrates how to get the latest modified list item using CSOM API in PS:

```
Function GetLastModified-ListItem(){

Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$ListTitle

)

   $list = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
   $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
   $query.ViewXml = '<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>'
   $items = $list.GetItems($query)
   $Web.Context.Load($items)
   $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
   return $items[0]
}
```

> Depending on the SharePoint version, SharePoint Client Components SDK
>   have to be installed in order to use CSOM API, here is [the link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)
>   for SharePoint 2013

Usage

```
$item = GetLastModified-ListItem -Web $ctx.Web -ListTitle "Documents"
$fileToDownloadUrl = $webUrl + $item["FileRef"]
```